# Safe conversion to integer and then test

Tags: groovy

I have the user input a value which always comes in as a string. In some cases, I know I will be able to convert it to an integer but not in others. For example

'3' is good but
'3A' will not convert to an integer.

In the cases it can convert to an integer, I need to compare its value to another integer so I am trying to do something this like:

```
if (valueToBeTested.toInteger().getClass == java.lang.Integer 
    && valueToBeTested.toInteger() >= 5) {
// do whatever
}
```

The only problem is that `toInteger(`) will not return a result when it can't convert something to an integer so how can I safely perform the test in my `if` condition? I perform the first test to try and see if it successfully converted to an integer, the second test is obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (valueToBeTested.isInteger() && valueToBeTested.toInteger() >= 5 ) { .. }
```

`isNumber()` can be used when any number (integer, float, double) is expected.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will `isInteger()` also be ok to use?

Comment: Yes it will make more sense if you are not expecting `valueToBeTested` to be a float or double value or any value other than integer. Updating my answer.